# VBA time difference in seconds

Tags: excel, vba

I want to make an activity to happen only when there is minimum 60 seconds time gap between two successive activities. I have the below code:

```
Sub timediff()
    Dim Psos As New Collection
    Dim currtime As Date
    Dim dummytime As Date
    Dim diffoftime As Long

    If Psos.Count = 0 Then
        dummytime = "9:00:00"
        Psos.Add dummytime
    End If

    currtime = Format(Now(), "hh:mm:ss")
    diffoftime = DateDiff("s", CDate(Psos.Item(Psos.Count)), CDate(currtime))

    If diffoftime > 60 Then
        Debug.Print diffoftime
        Psos.Add currtime
    End If
End Sub
```

But I'm always getting the time difference from 9:00:00 to current time instead of time difference between current time and latest added collection item. Would anyone suggest the issue.

Comment: As per the code, if `dummytime = "9:00:00"`, the `currtime` will not be added in the collection if the `currtime` is before `9:59:59`.

Comment: ehm your last added collection item in your actual code **always** is `dummytime` which is `9:00:00`. I mean you define a new and empty `Dim Psos As New Collection` that means `Psos.Count = 0` that means `Psos.Add dummytime` and then you calculate the difference between last item (which is `dummytime`) and `currtime`. There cannot be any other result.

Comment: Thanks. missed the simple logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you call timediff, Psos is reset to empty... Not sure why a collection is needed, just make a global Date variable and compare to it, or do everything in one procedure:

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr)

Public Sub OneMinuteLoop()
    Dim dtmNow As Date
    Dim dtmLastUpdate As Date

    Do While True
        dtmNow = Now()
        If DateDiff("s", dtmLastUpdate, dtmNow) > 30 Then
            'Do something
            dtmLastUpdate = dtmNow
        End If
        Sleep 5000
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. Would check on this & revert.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply take the difference between two results of the `Now()` worksheet function, and multiply it with 86400, without any formatting?

`Now()` gives the datetime of now, where units are days. As there are 86400 seconds within one day, the multiplication of the difference with 86400 will give you the amount of seconds.